# Taxes on money gift from abroad

Tags: united-states, gift-tax

Would I be taxed on money gift from abroad? Consider the amount is larger than 100k. If yes, what is the rate? If no, do I still have to file some particular tax form on it as well?

Answer (score 2):

The US gift tax is to be paid by the giftor, not the recipient. So *you* should not be taxed for that gift in any way.

Comment: It's an interesting question, I wonder how the US authorities would "deal with that" ?

Comment: @Fattie As the giftor is NOT US Tax resident; the rules don't apply to the giftor. So if you are thinking IRS would chase a Non Resident, it is not the case.

Comment: You're sure?  It's commonplace that the IRS declares a person/entity "US connected".

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that **you must report it**.

https://www.bpbcpa.com/international-tax-2/avoiding-the-tax-traps-of-gifts-from-foreign-sources-by-lewis-kevelson-cpa/

"The IRS requires U.S. taxpayers to file Form 3520..."

Unsurprisingly there are a number of "traps" ..

"For example, foreign family members should not make “gifts” to their U.S. family members from a foreign corporation, since the IRS will consider such transfers to be taxable corporate dividends that cannot qualify as tax-free gifts."

https://www.fool.com/knowledge-center/the-tax-law-on-foreign-cash-gifts.aspx

"However, separate IRS regulations require recipients to report a foreign cash gift. IRS Form 3520 is required if you receive more than $100,000 from a nonresident alien or a foreign estate. In addition, gifts from foreign corporations or partnerships are subject to a lower threshold that is adjusted for inflation each year. For 2016, gifts of more than $15,671 trigger the filing requirement. You won't owe any tax as a result of filing these documents. However, failing to file them can result in IRS penalties."

You can google many entries on this.